# react-native eject error Unrecognized command "eject"

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I'm trying to eject my app to generate Android folder. I knew it worked before, but when I type `react-native eject` in my React Native project's root directory I'm getting:

```
can-mbp:MyApp can$ react-native eject
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
warn Package "bugsnag-react-native" is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please notify its maintainers about it.
warn Package "react-native-onesignal" is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please notify its maintainers about it.
warn Package react-native-onesignal has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Unknown option dependency.platforms.ios.sourceDir with value ""./ios"" was found. This is either a typing error or a user mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
error Unrecognized command "eject".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
```

I've searched for it but every answer points out to that `react-native eject` is simply the correct form and I couldn't find anything regarding that it doesn't work.

Here is my system info from `react-native info` command:

```
 System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7920HQ CPU @ 3.10GHz
    Memory: 62.21 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
    Xcode: 10.2/10E125 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.0-rc.2 => 0.60.0-rc.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whats the react native cli version?

Comment: @Victor CLI is 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Since create-react-native-app is deprecated this functionality is no longer needed.`

Due to [this pr](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275) it's gone!

Personaly I don't like it but run `npx react-native init YourProjectName` and copy over what's necessary.

**Update :** 
I copied to removed code and made a small package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-eject

Answer (score 1):

Always working for me, first install in your project

```
yarn add react-native-eject
```

and then run

```
react-native eject
```

make sure you have install yarn in your pc

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command 
npx react-native eject